# Generating multiple ggmaps (google) with a for-loop

Tags: r, google-maps, for-loop, ggmap

So I'm trying to output many google maps using a for loop.

The STRANGE thing is that if I type `(i = 1; i = 2)` it works, but if I use the for loop it does not!

```
## THIS WORKS:

rand.coord <- cbind(rnorm(10, 40, 40),lat=rnorm(10, 40, 40))

i = 1  

df <- data.frame(cbind(lon=rand.coord[i,1],lat=rand.coord[i,2] ))
map <- get_map(location = df, source = "google", zoom = 4, scale = 2, 
       maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(map) 


i = 2 
df <- data.frame(cbind(lon=rand.coord[i,1],lat=rand.coord[i,2] ))
map <- get_map(location = df, source = "google", zoom = 4, scale = 2, 
       maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(map) 

#THIS DOES NOT WORK:

for ( i in 1:10){
    df <- data.frame(cbind(lon=rand.coord[i,1],lat=rand.coord[i,2] ))
    map <- get_map(location = df, source = "google", zoom = 4, scale = 2, 
           maptype = "satellite")
    ggmap(map) 
   }
```

Comment: try `print(ggmap(map))`